# Using spinner values to search database

Tags: android, sql, database

I am new to programming in Android and I am trying to create an app where a user can choose some options from 2 spinners and after tapping on the search button, the app will search through a database based on the options selected and the results will show. The problem is I'm not sure what parameters to put into db.rawQuery to search using the values of the selected spinner options. I have tried to put in a rough guess below, but it is not working and I'm not sure how to make it search using both criteria.

Here is the coding for the spinner:

```
public class First extends Activity {

private Spinner foodSpinner, locationSpinner;
private Button btnSubmit;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first);
    addListenerOnButton();
}
public void addListenerOnButton() {

    foodSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.foodSpinner);
    locationSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.locationSpinner);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(First.this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("FOODSPINNER", foodSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            intent.putExtra("LOCATIONSPINNER", locationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            First.this.startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

}
```

Here is the coding for the search:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;
    protected String foodItemChosen;
    protected String locationItemChosen;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        foodItemChosen = getIntent().getExtras().getString("FOODSPINNER");
        locationItemChosen = extras.getString("LOCATIONSPINNER");
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    }


    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultDetails.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("FOOD_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void search(View view) {
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name, address FROM database WHERE food LIKE ?", 
                new String[]{"%" '+foodItemChosen+' "%"});
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, 
                R.layout.result_list_item, 
                cursor, 
                new String[] {"name", "address"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.address});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you are calling the method `search`?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but the xml for the button is:                                    <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/searchButton"
  android:text="Search"
  android:onClick="search"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_width="70dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/search"/>                                     I'm guessing that the method is called due to the onClick properties of the button? Correct me if im wrong!

Comment: Ok, but why you need the search Activity? can you tell me the flow of activities?

Comment: ok here is how it goes: a screen with 2 spinners (foodSpinner and locationSpinner) and a button will first appear. After the user have selected the options from the spinners and hit the button, the app is supposed to search through the data base (using the value from foodSpinner to search through column "food" and the value from locationSpinner to search through column "location" from a database). A list will then be displayed to show the relevant entries from the database

Comment: Then why you are having `public class Search extends Activity...`? What is the output you are getting by clicking the button?

Comment: I think I get what you mean. I should just remove the search activity as it does not seem to be needed right? By clicking the button, i hope to pass the spinner values into a new activity which will search through the database based on the values and list the relevant entries

Comment: can you post the layout of your listActivity?

Comment: Thank you for being so patient! I have tested the coding and everything works fine. I managed to figure out how to make a query based on the foodSpinner value but I am not sure how to query based on the foodSpinner value AND locationSpinner value. This is how I did it:                                                               cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name, address FROM database WHERE food LIKE ?", new String[]{"%" + foodItemChosen + "%"});     But how do I make a search with this additional criteria: WHERE location LIKE ?", new String[]{"%" + locationItemChosen + "%"}   ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then it is better to use [`query`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method instead of `rawQuery`. It provides flexible way to select items from the database.

Some useful articles

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android

Comment: thank you for your help! I looked through them but I keep having problems with query method as I have no prior experience and I'm not too familiar with the syntax. I figured out the way for rawQuery using the following:           cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name, address FROM database WHERE food LIKE ? AND location LIKE ?", new String[]{"%" + foodItemChosen + "%","%" + locationItemChosen + "%"});